# Find the equation of a plane

Tags: multivariable-calculus, analytic-geometry

Find the equation of a plane that passes through point $P(1,5,1)$, and is perpendicular to the planes $2x+y-2z=2$ and $x+3z=4$

My only guess so far is that we can obtain the plane's normal vector using $2x+y-2z=2$ but I'm clueless on how to involve  $x+3z=4$

Comment: Write it as $x+0\cdot y+3z=4$. (You want to take the cross product of the normal vectors.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$n_1=(2,1,-2),n_2=(1,0,3)$ and $n=n_1×n_2$ then $$[(x,y,z)-(1,5,1)].n=0$$